# VSCode: Changed keybinding is not effective when editing Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I changed the keybinding as below

```json
    {
        "key": "tab",
        "command": "-acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "tab",
        "command": "selectNextSuggestion",
        "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
    }
```

This successfully changed the behavior of tab key as desired when I am coding scripts such as `.py` `.html` etc.
Yet, the above gets inactive when I am coding on `.ipynb` with official python extension.
Would it be possible to carry those settings to Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Currently, VS Code does not support setting this function in Jupyter notebook, please use the shortcut key "down" or "Ctrl+down".

Comment: I see, thank you so much for the comment!